# Preventing field input duplication across routes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have two forms that are duplicates of each other on different pages on my application, that perform slightly different functions. They look like this (stripping out extra code):

```
<form role="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="processForm()"
    novalidate>
    <div>
        <fieldset id="basicForm">       
            <div id="firstname" class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group" id="inputSection">
                    <input id="firstNameInput" title="Input first name"
                        type="text" class="form-control form-custom basicInput"
                        name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"
                        ng-model="myForm.formData.firstname" maxlength="20"
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this:

```
<form role="form" name="myFormCopy" ng-submit="processForm()"
    novalidate>
    <div>
        <fieldset id="basicForm">       
            <div id="firstname" class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group" id="inputSection">
                    <input id="firstNameInput" title="Input first name"
                        type="text" class="form-control form-custom basicInput"
                        name="firstname" placeholder="First Name"
                        ng-model="myFormCopy.formData.firstname" maxlength="20"
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, these fields are identical except the forms have a different name, and a different ng-model.

I notice, when changing from one page in the application to another, if I have typed into this field on one page, that text will automatically be in the matching field on the other page. Trying to debug it, it seems like the data in the model on one page will be duplicated in the model on the other page.

Is there a way to avoid this? Even changing the model name (e.g. myForm.formData.firstname and myFormCopy.formData.firstnamecopy), then there simply exists a firstname and firstnamecopy in each model. What the hell is going on here?

Comment: You are having same `ng-model`, that is why same data is showing on both change. Basically you need to change the `ng-model` of one of the page.

Comment: How are you initially populating `myForm`?  From your description it sounds that you've wound up making `myForm` and `myFormCopy` references to the same javascript object.

Comment: @PankajParkar they do not have the same ng-model if you look more closely.

Comment: @DanielBeck not sure exactly what you mean by how I am initially populating it? However, based on what Patrick said below it sounds like you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variable "formData" most likely is the exact same instance of object for both forms.
objects are referenced in javascript, say you do

```
var o1 = { a: 99 };
var o2 = o1;
o2.a = 100;
console.log (o1);
```

then you will get that a is 100 because when you change o2 you do change o1 as well since its the very same object.
if you do not want this to happen you will have to create a so called deep copy (you will urgently have to google that term if you don't know it yet)
of the first object.
how to do that depends on the allowed frameworks you have access to.
in jQuery this for example would be a solution:

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

Comment: I didn't end up needing to use a "deep copy", but you made me realize that the variable "formData" wasn't like automatically generated or anything, so I simply created a formDataCopy variable and the problem is solved.

Didn't know about the referencing in Javascript, so thanks!